# Lodash filter for multiple values for a single key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

In Lodash filter we can do

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false }
];

_.filter(users, _.matches({ 'age': 36, 'active': true }));

// result { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true }
```

But what I want to do is

```
_.filter(users, _.matches({ 'age': [36, 40] }));

// result
{ 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
{ 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false }
```

```js
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false }
]

console.log( _.filter(users, _.matches({ 'age': 36, 'active': true })) )

// result 
// { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true }

console.log( _.filter(users, _.matches({ 'age': [36, 40] })) )

// result
// { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
// { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I suppose it all depends ***on your*** definition on what a match means with `matches({ 'age': [36, 40] })`. Is it a range? If so are the bounds inclusive/exclusive? Is it a list that needs to include the age value of the elements being iterated? Your example is a bit inconclusive since the input matches the output, so it's unclear what was filtered. And I would also say that using lodash for filtering an array is probably overkill since [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) exists.

Comment: I made you a very generic function here
   

     const FindMatch = (attr,item,arr)=>{
        return arr.includes(item[attr])
        }
        
        _.filter(users, (item)=> return{ FindMatch('age',item, [36, 40])})

Comment: Apologies, I should've been more specific, I've posted a new one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68506347/lodash-filter-matching-for-multiple-values-in-nested-objects

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting the ages in an array and check whether it includes the item's `age` property:

```js
var users=[{user:"barney", age:36, active:!0}, {user:"fred", age:40, active:!1}, {user:"stackoverflow", age:12, active:!0}];
const validAges = [36, 40];
const result = _.filter(users, (o) => { return validAges.includes(o.age)})
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can just use plain [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var users=[{user:"barney", age:36, active:!0}, {user:"fred", age:40, active:!1}, {user:"stackoverflow", age:12, active:!0}];
const validAges = [36, 40];
const result = users.filter(e => validAges.includes(e.age));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Apologies, I should've been more specific, I've posted a new one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68506347/lodash-filter-matching-for-multiple-values-in-nested-objects