# Lodash filter matching for multiple values in nested objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have an array of objects

```
const obj = [
    {
        "id": 20000,
        "attributes": [
            {
                "name": "Size",
                "value": "38"
            },
            {
                "name": "Color",
                "value": "Blue"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 20056,
        "attributes": [
            {
                "name": "Size",
                "value": "38"
            },
            {
                "name": "Color",
                "value": "Brown"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and I have another object to match it against with

```
const selectedAttributes = {
    "Color": "Brown",
    "Size": "38"
}
```

**the desired result after matching**

- Matching `obj` with `selectedAttributes` should return the `second entry` in obj

**What I am trying**

Since we cannot provide multiple values in the ._matches property this doesn't work

```
matchingVariations = _.filter(obj, _.flow(
    _.property('attributes'),
    _.partialRight(_.some, { name: ['Size', 'Color'], value: ['Brown', '38'] })
))
```

*Expected Output*

```
[
    {
    "id": 20056,
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "Size",
            "value": "38"
        },
        {
            "name": "Color",
            "value": "Brown"
        }
    ]
    }   
]
```

```js
const obj = [
    {
        "id": 20000,
        "attributes": [
            {
                "name": "Size",
                "value": "38"
            },
            {
                "name": "Color",
                "value": "Blue"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 20056,
        "attributes": [
            {
                "name": "Size",
                "value": "38"
            },
            {
                "name": "Color",
                "value": "Brown"
            }
        ]
    }
]

const selectedAttributes = {
    "Color": "Brown",
    "Size": "38"
}

const selectedAttributes2 = {
    "Size": "38"
}

const matchingVariations = _.filter(obj, _.flow(
    _.property('attributes'),
    _.partialRight(_.some, { name: 'Size', value: '38' })
))

const matchingVariations2 = _.filter(obj, _.flow(
    _.property('attributes'),
    _.partialRight(_.some, { name: ['Size', 'Color'], value: ['Brown', '38'] })
))

console.log(matchingVariations);
console.log(matchingVariations2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you  add what's the expected output? Would be much easier to understand

Comment: @Orville added and made simpler let me know if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a library, you could directly use `Array#filter` to obtain only specific elements.

`Object.entries` can be used to get the key-value pairs of the selected attributes, `Array#every` can be used to ensure that all entries match a given condition, and `Array#some` can be used to check that the key and value exist in the attributes array of the object.

```js
const obj=[{id:2000,attributes:[{name:"Size",value:"38"},{name:"Color",value:"Blue"}]},{id:20056,attributes:[{name:"Size",value:"38"},{name:"Color",value:"Brown"}]}];
const selectedAttributes = {
    "Color": "Brown",
    "Size": "38"
}
const selectedAttributes2 = {
    "Size": "38"
}
const matches = (arr, attrs)=>arr.filter(x => 
  Object.entries(attrs).every(([k, v])=>
    x.attributes.some(a => a.name === k && a.value === v
)));
console.log(matches(obj, selectedAttributes));
console.log(matches(obj, selectedAttributes2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important;top:0}
```